# Bootstrap and XSLT - Collapse component - how to generate dynamic ID in for each loop

Tags: html, xml, xslt, bootstrap-4

I have the following XSLT transformation with Bootstrap.

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/customers/customer">
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id">Link</button>
    </div>  
    <div id="id" class="collapse">
      <xsl:value-of select="price"/>      
    </div>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I need to generate unique `data-target="#id"` each time I go through the loop so I can link to different divs. The transformed HTML should look like this.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="1">Link</button>
  </div>  
  <div id="1" class="collapse">
    10   
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="2">Link</button>
  </div>  
  <div id="2" class="collapse">
    13   
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="3">Link</button>
  </div>  
  <div id="3" class="collapse">
    22   
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way hot to achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: You can use `position()` or `generate-id()` to generate a different value for each `customer`.

Comment: Many thanks! It is working perfectly.

Here is the solution I used:
<xsl:for-each select="data/customers/customer">
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{generate-id()}">Link</button>
    </div>  
    <div id="{generate-id()}" class="collapse">
      <xsl:value-of select="price"/>      
    </div>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>